# Excel 2019 - Use Linear Regression to Estimate X from known Ys

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a simple formula to get a new X from a known Y using linear regression. I am aware that I could just rearrange the Y = MX + B equation from a scatter plot, and that I can get those values from SLOPE() and INTERCEPT() or LINEST(). But I swear I saw a function that takes known Xs, known Ys, a known Y, and returns a new X for that Y, but for the life of me I can't remember it.

There are functions that give a new Y from a known X, but I'm looking for the opposite. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is called FORECAST.

It is intended to return the y value for a new x ie. y = FORECAST(x, ydata, xdata) but can easily be modified to be used "in reverse" to calculate x given a new y:

```
=FORECAST(y, xdata, ydata)
```

This is because the inverse function of a linear polynomial function is still just a linear polynomial, i.e.

```
if y = m x + b  then 
  x = (1/m) y - b/m
if y' = x and x' = y then
  y' = m' x' + b' with m' = 1/m and b' = -b/m
```